# I am using Python 3.9.4 and Django 3.2 and I made a function and a form that to check if the username or email already exists

Tags: python, django

I am getting an error tuple indices must be integers or slices, not User also tuple indices must be integers or slices, not NoneType I am checking whether any of these username or email exists or not, also the exists() not working only first() not working note I am using python 3.9.4

```
if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists() or User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
    error_message = ''
    email_error = ('', 'Email is taken. ')[User.objects.filter(email=email).exists()]
    username_error = ('', 'Username is taken. ')[User.objects.filter(username=username).exists()]
    error_message = email_error + username_error
    messages.success(request, error_message)
    return redirect('/register/')
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `email_error = ('', 'Email is taken. ')[User.objects....` ? This is the error cause, because you are trying to slice tuple by queryset

Comment: Do you want to validate the username field in a sign up view?

Comment: I have registration form where there are fields like username email so I am checking that if any user is previously registered or not by entering username or email but it does not work it should display a message that username is taken or email is taken

Comment: No I want to check username or email exists or not and display a message

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
email_error = ('', 'Email is taken. ')[User.objects.filter(email=email).exists()]
```

you are creating a tuple with the part `('', 'Email is taken. ')`. Then you are trying to get the value of a specific index for this tuple using the third brackets `[ ]`. However, you are passing a boolean value while trying to access the value being stored in an index of this tuple.

It seems to me that you have some confusion about tuples or what doing this `('', 'Email is taken. ')` actually does.

**Possible Solution for this:** Note that this is my way of solving this and this can differ from people to people.

```
is_duplicate_username = User.objects.filter(username=username).exists()
is_duplicate_email = User.objects.filter(email=email).exists()
if is_duplicate_username or is_duplicate_email:
    error_message = ''
    error_message = error_message + 'Email is taken' if is_duplicate_email else error_message
    error_message = error_message + 'Username is taken' if is_duplicate_username else error_message
    messages.success(request, error_message)
    return redirect('/register/')
```